# insert a picture from android to database

Tags: java, android, mysql

in my project, i got a problem about insert a picture from android to database.
i have success insert a picture from gallery mobile but not work insert from a camera mobile.
This my source code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaColumns.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            pathToOurFile = filePath;
            format = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1,
                    filePath.length());
            this.imGambar.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get(
                    "data"));

        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            pathToOurFile = filePath;
            format = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1,
                    filePath.length());
            this.imGambar
                    .setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not work" ? Any log trace ? More infos please.

Comment: if I turn button save this application has stopped

Answer (score 0):

This method doesn't work fine to get Uri in request camera activity result. You'd better use :

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mImageCaptureUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); 
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

And in the onActivityResult :

```
String path = mImageCaptureUri.toString();
```

where

```
Uri mImageCaptureUri ;
```

is a global variable.

Hope it helps...